# Can flood type attacks occur if there isn't a signer for updating data on a PDA?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, security

So this is just something I've been thinking about.
Hypothetically, if I had a PDA where anybody can call similar to the basic example below..

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, data: u64) -> Result<()> {
        ctx.accounts.my_account.data = data;
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct MyAccount {
    data: u64
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct SetData<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub my_account: Account<'info, MyAccount>
}
```

and there is no signer, would the PDA be susceptible to some type of "flood attack", where any body can just trigger it over and over and cause the app to crash or slow down other legitimate updates to the PDA?

My apologies if I'm way off on my thinking here, just trying to understand a broader picture of what would happen in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would work just like any other transaction. If there's a write lock on the account, the transaction scheduler needs to execute all transactions referencing the account serially, and that account would be able to use at most 12 million compute units in a block.

This means that your program would be throttled by the runtime due to the write locks. There's no impact on whether it's a signing PDA or not, it's entirely based on the write lock and the compute usage on the account.

Comment: So does this mean it would disrupt all activity for the entire program (updates and reads) not just for this the one function?

Comment: If that PDA account is required for the other functions, yes